# sum matrix if greater than one EXCEL Function

Tags: arrays, excel, function, matrix

I have a matrix 3x4, I want to subtract 2 for each cell and I need the sum off all cell that is greater than zero. see image below that answer should be 22

```
0  1  5
3  4  1
3  8  9
4  2  0
```

[image]

I tried manually but I need to convert this into function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=LET(
    a,A1:C4-2,
    SUM((a>0)*a))
```

[image]

Older Versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:C4-2>0)*(A1:C4-2))
```